# how can I round integer breaks in choropleth map with tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I made a choropleth map with tm_polygons (not a reproductible example)

```
label <- labels_rec %>%
filter(VAR == sgf_var & TABLEAU == tab)

map <- tm_shape(sgf_polyg) +
tm_polygons(col = "V137", style = "equal", title="sgf_var",
          , textNA = "Valeur manquante", 
          legend.hist = TRUE,
          legend.format=list(fun=function(x) formatC(x, digits=0, format="f"), 
text.separator= "-")) +
tm_borders("#9E9E9E") +
tm_layout(main.title = label$LIBELLE, main.title.size = 0.5,legend.outside = TRUE, 
legend.title.size = 0.7, legend.hist.width = 1)
```

I want to round my integer digits
example :
20000 to 23000
23000 to 26000
26000 to 29000 etc.

`formatC(x, digits=0, format="f")` can be only used with decimal numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of the default example from `?tmap::tm_polygons` you could achieve your desired result via the formatting function `formatC(formatC(floor(x / 1000) * 1000, digits = 0, format = "f")`:

```r
library(tmap)

data(World)

# Constant fill
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_fill(
    col = "gdp_cap_est", style = "equal", title = "sgf_var",
    textNA = "Valeur manquante",
    legend.hist = TRUE,
    legend.format = list(fun = function(x) formatC(formatC(floor(x / 1000) * 1000, digits = 0, format = "f")), text.separator = "-")
  ) +
  tm_borders("#9E9E9E")
```

[image]